Erratic Timing on Slick Slider
I've got a section where there two Slick sliders, one on top of the other, going in different directions.  They're both on autoplay with the same settings, but at times they seem to independently speed up/slow down.  I've also noticed that at certain times there are not images displaying (even thought the settings are set to infinite).  I would expect them to move at the exact same speed with continuous rows of images.  Anyone know what the issue might  be?  Very grateful for any help figuring this out.
  <main class="main">
        <div class="slider">
            <div id="top-slider">
                <img src="https://e47sandbox.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Mask-group-1.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://e47sandbox.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Mask-group-2.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://e47sandbox.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Mask-group-3.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://e47sandbox.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Mask-group-4.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://e47sandbox.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Mask-group-5.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div dir="rtl" id="bottom-slider">
                <img src="https://e47sandbox.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Mask-group-1.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://e47sandbox.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Mask-group-2.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://e47sandbox.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Mask-group-3.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://e47sandbox.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Mask-group-4.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://e47sandbox.wpenginepowered.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/Mask-group-5.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.site-container {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 100px 0;
}

#top-slider {
    padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

#bottom-slider {
    padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
}

(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#top-slider').slick({
      pauseOnHover: false,
      dots: false,
      arrows: false,
      infinite: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 1,
      cssEase: 'linear',
      speed: 6000,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      variableWidth: true,
      pauseOnHover: false,
    });

    $('#bottom-slider').slick({
      pauseOnHover: false,
      dots: false,
      arrows: false,
      infinite: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 1,
      cssEase: 'linear',
      speed: 7000,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      variableWidth: true,
      rtl: true
    });
  });
})(jQuery);

I have a codepen too:https://codepen.io/paul-molnar/pen/wvZmaKj
